# how is a Jewish war leader dedicated?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, army-military-war

As I recall from some passages, there were times when a priest had to anoint a war-leader... not necessarily a king, but sometimes a dedicated warrior to handle an emergency.   Can an expert in sword (either broadsword where sitting vigil is a Christian dedication ritual, or even such as katana where an expert not answering to a master is considered by the culture of that training to be 'ronin', masterless or undedicated) choose to dedicate him or herself to the defence of the Jewish People, and does a Kohen still have the power as a descendant of priests to perform that dedication?

Comment: this might be what you are thinking of: http://www.torah.org/learning/ravfrand/5771/shoftim.html

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, nothing that grandiose.

There was a civilian Kohen Gadol (high priest), and then there was his military equivalent, known as the *mashuach milchama* -- the Kohen appointed for war. The *mashuach milchama*'s job was basically to give the troops a big sermon before the battle, that's about it. He was given the *Kohen Gadol* status the same way his civilian counterpart was -- either through special anointing oil, or through wearing the special clothes for a few days.

As today there's no Temple, there is neither civilian *Kohen Gadol* nor a *mashuach milchama* (though obviously, today's Israeli Defense Forces have rabbi chaplains).